# Chrome Typescript debugging references wrong 'this'

Tags: debugging, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes when I hit a breakpoint in the Chrome Developer Tools, the TypeScript `this` is actually `_this` in the JavaScript. I have to manually put `_this` in the console to see what is actually being used. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> the TypeScript this is actually _this in the JavaScript

This is due to a bug in the sourcemaps. You can track it here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2859