# Node Server debugger code behavior changes when debugging

Tags: node.js, debugging, typescript, webstorm

I am debugging a Node Server written in typescript in WebStorm 10.0.4 and when stepping through the code, the code execution path completely changes. A variable assignment appears to break and reference a different (incorrect) object and break my code.

I have a class `CustomerRoutes.ts` which contains different methods to handle `POST` requests. I register the endpoint:

```
app.post('/Contacts', jsonParser, CustomerRoutes.postContact);
```

`CustomerRoutes.postContact` is a `public static` function which is defined as:

```
public static postContact(request, response) {
    if(request.body.$type == 'Person') {
        CustomerRoutes.postIndividual(request, response);
    } else if(request.body.$type == 'Organization') {
        CustomerRoutes.postOrganization(request, response);
    }
}
```

`CustomerRoutes.postIndividual` and `CustomerRoutes.postOrganization` are both `public static` functions as well. So when the server is in non-debug mode the code executes as expected and the branching statements are executed. However when stepping through the code the variable `CustomerRoutes` global variable gets reassigned to the contents of `request` within the scope of `CustomerRoutes.postContact`

[image]

As you can see in the Variables window of the debugger the variable `CustomerRoutes` has been redefined twice to the values of `request` and `response`. So now when stepping through the code and the functions `postIndividual` and `postOrganization` are called, `CustomerRoutes` does not contain those function and `POST` fails with an exception and error 500.

I do not believe this is any sort of race/timing condition so it must be a bug in the debugger environment. My hunch is that the typescript variable mappings are not working correctly with the debugger but I am not certain. Has anyone seen an issue like this or an idea on a fix? I have never seen anything like it. I am happy to post more information as requested.

Answer (score 0):

> My hunch is that the typescript variable mappings are not working correctly with the debugger but I am not certain.

TypeScript doesn't have proper *variable mapping* in sourcemaps at the moment. Follow this issue : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2859 (also answered it here once : [Chrome Typescript debugging references wrong 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346989/chrome-typescript-debugging-references-wrong-this/31351458#31351458))

> Has anyone seen an issue like this or an idea on a fix?

Disable sourcemaps to see what is actually going on in the raw JavaScript.