# Is there a way to avoid the infamous that = this in typescript

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if typescript provides a way to avoid the infamous :

```
let that = this
```

By instance, I have a class calling a web api to which I am subscribing, and to have my reference of the class in the subscribe, I did create a variable for the `this`.

```
class Foo {
   f = {}
   let that = this 
   this.http.get(foo)
   .subscribe {
      res => that.f = res 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The `let that = this` is not necessary when using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). An arrow function lexically binds the `this` value.

Observe that when writing this code:

```
class Foo {
    f = {};

    someMethod() {
        someFunction(res => this.f = res)
    }
}
```

The ES5 JavaScript output does the `let that = this` for you (as `var _this = this`):

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.f = {};
    }
    Foo.prototype.someMethod = function () {
        var _this = this;
        someFunction(function (res) { return _this.f = res; });
    };
    return Foo;
}());
```

Comment: Ty sir ! It works just fine. The chrome console was not accurate, but I did a test and it works

Comment: @user1058398 if you are using sourcemaps they might lie to you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346989/chrome-typescript-debugging-references-wrong-this/31351458#31351458 Also be cautious about arrow functions *when you do want `this` to come from the calling lib* https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html :)