# Typescript not operator not working

Tags: angular, typescript, operators, boolean-logic

I have this function that runs after a multiselect element is changed that sets an error message visibility:

```
  getVisibility(multiselect) {
    if ((multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && !multiselect.allSelected) && this.submitted) {
      return 'visible'
    } else {
      return 'hidden'
    }
  }
```

However in this line:

```
if ((multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && !multiselect.allSelected) && this.submitted)
```

multiselect.allSelected is false, but !multiselect.allSelected is also false.

picture1:

[image]

picture2:

[image]

Why is the ! (not) the same boolean value as without the not?

Comment: That's just source maps playing with your head. Disable source maps or debug directly from Visual Studio Code to gain some sanity back. Source maps in the devtools are really unreliable when breaking and debugging for some reason beyond me.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks, I don't suppose you have any idea how to on chrome for mac? I don't see any sources heading in settings such as this answer suggests http://stackoverflow.com/a/35004929/3935156

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins are you using webpack ? if so set devtool to "inline-source-map". This is a Chrome issue.

Comment: @ShlomiAssaf I don't think I'm using webpack

Answer (score 0):

> Typescript not operator not working

Its just JavaScript in the end and it most definitely works. The issue with the chrome dev tools and / or TypeScript source maps.

What I do:

- Execute the command in the console (hovers can lie).
- Disable source maps (More reasons : [Chrome Typescript debugging references wrong 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346989/chrome-typescript-debugging-references-wrong-this/31351458#31351458))