# Error launching Chrome Debugger for Visual Studio Code

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Chrome Debugging for VS Code. I'm only doing this because I use Chrome on a mac to debug, and I don't know how to disable source maps in Chrome on a mac, which is causing the debugging to be very buggy. [See my question about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39186189/3935156). But I keep getting this error when I try to launch the Chrome debugger for Visual Studio Code no matter what I try:

> [debugger-for-chrome] Cannot connect to the target: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222

The url to my homepage is http://localhost:3000/

my launch.json file is:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/js/app",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that I have tried a few values in:

`"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/js/app"`

such as `${workspaceRoot}/app` which holds my typescript.

All of my js goes in a folder called js in the project root, but I would like to debug from the typescript if that is possible?

Here is my project structure:

[image]

How can I get the Chrome Debugger for Visual Studio Code to work?